# Regex that does not match specific words

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

1) using the c# regex

i currently have the following regex

```
^(abc|def)$
```

it returns true if the word is "abc" or "def"
what i need is for it to match anything but those two words, including strings that contain those words.
i currently do it like this

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("^(abc|def)$");

if(!rgx.IsMatch(somestring)){
// do stuff
}
```

what i want is a regex where i don't have to use the **!** operator. so i need something like (see the **!** operator in new regex, but it doesn't work.)

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("^(!(abc|def))$");

if(rgx.IsMatch(somestring)){
// do stuff
}
```

expected results for somestring

blah --> true

abc blah -->  true

abc --> false

def --> false

blah def --> true

Hope this makes sense.. thanks in advance.

and just to clarify, i'm not trying to find the word in a string, i want to compare the whole string to the regex... hence the **^()$**

as far as why not just use !rgx.IsMatch, let's just say i'm simply trying to see if it's possible with regex

Comment: not a duplicate, read the question... i'm looking for a whole word match not a match contained inside a string

Comment: If you are not trying to find word in a string using regex why use regex? Does string.Contains and simple condition won't work?

Comment: the "why" isn't important here. i wanted to see if it's possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this regex. It checks that the start mark `^` is not followed by `abc` or `def` until the end `$`.

```
^(?!(abc|def)$).*
```

Comment: Ty. i was actually tryng "^(?!(abc|def)$)" without the .* ... regex is wierd lol. tnx again

Comment: What a beautiful regex :)

Comment: For applying this as part of a larger pattern, use `(?!(abc|def)).*`